# Impact of move semantic on data structure in C++

Tags: c++, c++11, move-semantics, deque

I am creating a stl deque as a class member of unique_ptr and inside one of the class member function returning this deque with move semantic. I am not sure what will be the state of class member deque after the return, either the content of deque becomes null or this deque itself becomes null. Does this cause the memory leak also?

code snippet.

```
class test
{
    deque<type> m_q;
    public:
    void qEvent(type t);
    type&& getQedEvent(deque<type> &q);
};
void test::qEvent(type t)
{
    m_q.emplace_back(move(t));
}
test::deque&& test::getQedEvent(deque<type>& q)
{
    return move(q);
}
```

Comment: `getQedEvent` doesn't touch any class member in any way, so the state of the class member after the call is exactly the same as it was before the call. Did you mean to actually mention `m_q` in there somewhere? As written, `test{}.getQedEvent(q)` is exactly equivalent to `std::move(q)`

Comment: Thanks for your comment. You are right here, the getQedEvent(q) method is same as std::move(q). I wanted to know the state of m_q, which is a member of my class and it is std::deque. Is it a valid deque which I can use in my next Iteration?

Comment: Of course. Again, since `getQedEvent` doesn't touch `m_q` in any way, it's in the same state after that call as it was before that call. I'm not sure I understand the point of that method though - what exactly is it supposed to achieve? Why would anyone want to call it, if it just takes a parameter and returns it right back?

Comment: I am trying to have the class member m_q as a deque of event and have a processEvent() method  where I am creating local q and invoking the getQedevent(q). Most of time it is working as expected, but sometimes it is crashing. And I am not sure once we invoked getQedevent(q) inside processEvent(), what will be the state of class member m_q. Is it in a valid deque or becomes invalid after move. Hope this clarifies my question a bit.

Comment: Don't describe your code in prose, show the actual code. Prepare a [mcve]